# Ubuntu For Android. Is it available to the average Joe?

Tags: ubuntu-for-android

Ok so i was poking around on the internet looking to dual boot my laptop (windows 7 and ubuntu) and saw the ubuntu for android page and was super excited. I want to install the ubuntu full desktop os on my LG Optimus G Pro, but have a few questions. i poked around for answers but none were answered by the ubuntu site or forums i could find.

1. Is ubuntu for android something that can be added to existing phones, or is it something pre-installed on phones at purchase?
2. Where does one get the necessary docking device for the phone to connect to a monitor? Or again is it something that comes with specific phones?
3. I see lists of required specs EVERYWHERE but nothing saying how to actually get ubuntu for android.

Im a little frustrated about the lack of information on the main site about who, how, and when people can obtain ubuntu for android. I was pumped up for it by the page, but was a little disappointed that i could not find out how (or if) i can install it. i would really appreciate if someone can fill me in on ubuntu for android's status. Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify: Are you referring to Ubuntu touch (http://www.ubuntu.com/phone) or Ubuntu for Android (http://www.ubuntu.com/phone/ubuntu-for-android)?

Answer (score 0):

1. It's not pre-installed on phones (yet).  There have been announcements of phones with Ubuntu pre-installed, but not with the desktop switching mode, just with the Ubuntu Touch experience (for now).
2. Not out yet.
3. [Here's a list of devices!](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices) Since Ubuntu on phones is still really in pre-release mode, it's not really in average-Joe mode yet.  You could still have a stab at it if you have a supported device, though; [here is the install guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install).

So, Ubuntu for Android isn't where you want it to be right now.  The idea of having your current Android phone then plugging it into a dock and you have a full desktop is great, but it's not here yet.  You'll probably see Ubuntu phones hit the market early next year.

Comment: Please note though that Ubuntu touch != Ubuntu for android